# Async Await not working correctly with useStateCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I need to update same state in the sequence:

```
// lets say this is the state
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({a: 1, b: 1})

// and i need to update it like so
// from an external function     
setSomeState({a: 2})
// wait until the first one is actually updates
// and do the next one  
setSomeState({b: 2})
// wait until the second one is actually updates
// "tell" the parent function that both are updated
```

Now I do this:

```
// i use a customized hook useStateCallback
function useStateCallback(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer((state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }), initialState)
  const cbRef = useRef(null)

  const setStateCallback = (state, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb
    setState(state)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state)
      cbRef.current = null
    }
  }, [state])

  return [state, setStateCallback]
}

// and execute it like so
// from outside of a component
export const someFunction = async setState => {
    await setState({ a: 2 }, () => Promise.resolve())
    await setState({ b: 2 }, () => Promise.resolve())
}
```

but this callback doest work right, and the caller function doesn't actually wait for the state changes.

So my questions are:

1. How the useStateCallback hook works in conjunction with `Promise.resolve()`?
2. How `Promise.resolve()` works in this particular case?
3. How do I update same state one after another, when the second one will be updated only when the first one is updated (with hooks) and "tell" the parent function that they both finished it's updates?

Comment: We need more information about what `setState()` is. What does it return? What arguments does it take in?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your setup is that setStateCallback sets the callback ref and then returns. And then you call that callback from useEffect. The problem here is by the time useEffect gets called the original call function already completed.

If we just want to make sure we wait for setState to complete, then we would solve this as such by adding the useEffect within the setStateCallback and wrapping it in a promise. This will basically say, only resolve if useEffect completes. Otherwise just wait

```
  const setStateCallback = (state, cb) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
       cbRef.current = cb
       setState(state)
       useEffect(async () => {
          if (cbRef.current) {
            await cbRef.current(state) // Calls your wrap callback promise here in case there's anything you want to do. Otherwise you don't need that wrapper callback anymore and we can remove this await.
            cbRef.current = null
          }
          resolve();  --> This will basically resolve once useEffect is done calling the functions it needs to call. 
       }, [state])
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `setStateCallback` does not returns a `Promise`, but it accept a callback; that's why it can't be directly called with the `await` syntax. What you need is just a simple wrapper to *promisify* it.

Something like:

```
function useStateCallback(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer((state, newState) => ({ ...state,
    ...newState
  }), initialState)
  const cbRef = useRef(null)

  const setStateCallback = (state, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb
    setState(state)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state)
      cbRef.current = null
    }
  }, [state])

  const setStateAsync = state => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setStateCallback(state, resolve))

  return [state, setStateCallback, setStateAsync]
}
```

Now you can init your state as:

```
const [state, setStateCallback, setStateAsync] = useStateCallback({})
```

From now on you could use the `async` form `setStateAsync`. This mixed to a fixed `clear` function (this time it accepts an `async` function):

```
export const clear = async setState => {
    await setState({ isWritable: false })
    await setState({ isVisible: false })
}
```

should let you to use:

```
await clear(setStateAsync);
```

with the expected `async` behavior.

Comment: `Your setStateCallback does not returns a Promise, but it accept a callback; that's why it can't be directly called with the await syntax` but why it is retuning a promise, that I can see in a console and even get it's value (if I pass it through callback)? I actually want to understand how it works and what am I missing

Comment: The way that OP wrote his wrapper is already returning a promise. So no need to do another wrap on top of it. I do agree that we could return a promise within useStateCallback so that we don't have to create a wrapper every time. I think the actual issue is something else though. Here is his wrapper for reference.  `await setState({ a: 2 }, () => Promise.resolve())` It basically calls setState and it gives it a callback that returns a promise.